# How I can add checked rows from grid view to another girdview in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have two GridViews. The first grid view's first column is a checkbox.

How can I populate a second grid with the values of the checked rows from the first grid?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to have a for loop for taking all the rows together and one after another you need to check for the checkbox check property and for all those which are checked you need to add them into another dataset and then you have to assign that dataset to another grid.

Comment: thank u :) 
if i want to take one column value of the forst grid ...how can i do it ..

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed narrative here,

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Transfer-Selected-Rows-from-one-GridView-to-Another-in-Asp.net.aspx